# Problems creating a php form that sends data to database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to php, trying to make this simple form but I keep finding different examples of how to do it but they're all done with `mysql` and I've been told to switch to `mysqli`.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>

    </title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="process.php" method="post">
<table>
    <tr><th>Student Details</th></tr>
        <tr>
        <td><label for="student_name">Student Name</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="student_name" id="student_name"/> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="student_email">Student Email</label></td>
        <td><input type="email" name="student_email" id="student_email"/> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="student_city">Student City</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="student_city" id="student_city"/> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><button name= "submit"type="submit">Submit</button></td>

    </tr>

</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Could someone please look at this code and tell me how to:

A) Avoid the following errors:

> **Undefined variable:** insert in C:\Users\CEO\Google
>      Drive\Form\process.php on line 30
>
> **Warning:** mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given
>      in C:\Users\CEO\Google Drive\Form\process.php on line 30

B) Apparently this form is a total security risk, what should I add to fix that?

```
  <?php
    $server = 'localhost';
    $user = 'root';
    $pass = '';
    $db = 'college';
    $conn = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass, $db); //Connect to Database

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $name = $_POST['student_name'];
        $email = $_POST['student_email'];
        $city = $_POST['student_city'];
    if($name != "" || $email != "" || $city != ""){
    $insert = "INSERT INTO students(student_name, student_email,student_contact) VALUES ('$name','$email','$city')";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn,$insert);
        echo "Data inserted";
        }else{
            echo "Failed to insert data";
        }
    }

    if (!mysqli_query($insert, $conn)) {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
    }
    echo "1 record added";
    mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: you have $insert,$conn in wrong order on the bottom, mysqli_query expects paramater 1 to be mysqli ($conn)

Comment: Your form is not the problem (security risk), how you run the sql statement is. You have to `prepare` it and not put all the raw post values in there (don't do this `$name = $_POST['student_name'];` and throw those into the statement).

Comment: You're calling `mysqli_query()` outside the `if` block that assigns to `$insert`. So it will try to perform the query even if you haven't assigned the variable.

Comment: Could one of you please show me how to do it? I've been at this for 6 hours and I still have no idea what to do.

Comment: To make your for submission secure prepare and bind your post values: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: BTW, the `if` only requires one of the fields to be filled in. If they have to fill in all 3, you need to use `&&` instead of `||`.

Comment: `!mysqli_query($insert, $conn)`. It should be `!mysqli_query($conn, $insert)`. But you are already running that statement in your if statement (if at least one of the variables isn't empty).

Answer (score 3):

You assign to `$insert` inside the `if` block. But then you try to perform the query outside the `if` block. So if the `if` condition is not met, you'll still try to call `mysqli_query()`, but with an uninitialized variable. You should move that into the `if`.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $name = $_POST['student_name'];
    $email = $_POST['student_email'];
    $city = $_POST['student_city'];

    if($name != "" || $email != "" || $city != ""){
        $insert = "INSERT INTO students(student_name, student_email, student_contact)
          VALUES ('$name','$email','$city')";
        if (mysqli_query($conn,$insert)) {
            echo "Data inserted";
        }else{
            echo "Failed to insert data: " . mysqli_error($conn);
        }
    } else {
        echo "You have to fill in name, email, or city";
    }
}
```

But it's better to use prepared statements.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $name = $_POST['student_name'];
    $email = $_POST['student_email'];
    $city = $_POST['student_city'];

    if($name != "" || $email != "" || $city != ""){
        $insert = mysqli_prepare("INSERT INTO students(student_name, student_email, student_contact)
          VALUES (?, ?, ?)") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($insert, "sss", $name, $email, $city);
        if (mysqli_stmt_execute($insert)) {
            echo "Data inserted";
        }else{
            echo "Failed to insert data: " . mysqli_error($conn);
        }
    } else {
        echo "You have to fill in name, email, or city";
    }
}
```

Comment: if the user did submit only one field for example name
 email and city will be an undefined index and there is going to be error because there is no such values or it's going to insert them as null?

Comment: I just tried that but I get a blank screen, nothing gets inserted into the table but I dont even get an error message now :(

Comment: @Ahmadghoneim If it's a text field, it will always be submitted, it will just be an empty string.

Comment: This is still leaving me with a blank screen, no error messages now, but still no data uploaded to the table

Comment: What's on line 42?

Comment: I found my syntax error in the `mysqli_prepare()` call. I added an additional error check there. But I can't see any other problem. Try putting `echo` statements at different places in the code to see what it's executing.